# Web scraping Kaggle data

Tags: r, api

I am new to R. I am willing to import Kaggle data into R. I know that python has an inbuilt Kaggle API, that enables coder to pull the data.

Can I perform the similar task using R?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe one exists for R.  See this thread [here](https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/67421).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I found about that package yesterday.